# Components not rendered when receiving arrays from parents

Tags: reactjs, react-props

```
    data.Example.map((item) => {
        console.log(item.A)
        return <ExampleBlock
            a={item.A}
            b={item.B}
        />
    })
```

The data object in this code is imported from local json object. Here, console.log(item.A) just helps me to check if this is really an array.

```
    postList.forEach(post => {
        post.data.Example.map((item) => {
            console.log(item.A)
            return <ExampleBlock
                a={item.A}
                b={item.B}
            />
        })
    })
```

The postList here is imported from firestore. I exercise cautious here with console.log(item.A) and have verified that it's indeed an array like I drawn from local json file in the previous code set.

Both console.log shows the same thing.

Weird thing here is. The first set of code works just fine. It passed down the arrays as props and component is rendered perfect. The second set of code, the component wasn't rendered and it's just blank.

I've tried hard to think what's wrong and what's the difference. Would you guys please point me to the right direction. THanks.

Comment: Thanks you all. I figured it out. postList.map(post => {
      return  post.data.Example.map((item) => {
            console.log(item.A)
            return <ExampleBlock
                a={item.A}
                b={item.B}
            />
        })
    })

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the `forEach` which returns nothing. Replace it with a map as follows:

```
      postList
        .map((post) => post.data.Example)
        .map((item) => {
          console.log(item.A);
          return <ExampleBlock a={item.A} b={item.B} />;
        })
```

Comment: hi, thanks, i tried, it wont' rendered too